# Make randomized grid search parallel on sklearn estimator using joblib

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, joblib

I'm trying to run randomized grid search on a sklearn estimator but I do not want to cross-validate because I already have a train/validation/test split for my data.    I've built the function to run the randomized grid search but I'd like to parallelize across threads.  I've been looking at joblib and trying to figure out how to modify the Parallel(delayed(func)) functions but can't figure out how to implement on my code.

Here is my function:

```
def randomized_grid_search(model=None, param_grid=None, percent=0.5,
                           X_train=None, y_train=None, 
                           X_val=None, y_val=None):        
    # converts parameter grid into a list
    param_list = list(ParameterGrid(param_grid))
    # the number of combinations to try in the grid
    n = int(len(param_list) * percent)
    # the reduced grid as a list
    reduced_grid = sample(param_list, n)
    best_score = 0
    best_grid = None

    """ 
    Loops through each of the posibble scenarios and
    then scores each model with prediction from validation set.
    The best score is kept and held with best parameters.
    """ 
    for g in reduced_grid:
        model.set_params(**g)
        model.fit(X_train,y_train)
        y_pred = model.predict(X_val)
        recall = recall_score(y_val, y_pred)
        if recall > best_score:
            best_score = recall
            best_grid = g

    """
    Combines the training and validation datasets and 
    trains the model with the best parameters from the 
    grid search"""
    best_model = model
    best_model.set_params(**best_grid)
    X2 = pd.concat([X_train, X_val])
    y2 = pd.concat([y_train, y_val])
    return best_model.fit(X2, y2)
```

From https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html I think this the direction I need to head in:

```
with Parallel(n_jobs=2) as parallel:
    accumulator = 0.
    n_iter = 0
    while accumulator < 1000:
       results = parallel(delayed(sqrt)(accumulator + i ** 2)
                          for i in range(5))
       accumulator += sum(results)  # synchronization barrier
       n_iter += 1
```

Should I do something like this or am I approaching this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the built-in parallelization using the n_jobs parameter?

```
grid = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(..., n_jobs=-1)
```

The [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) documentation describes the n_jobs parameter as:

> n_jobs : int or None, optional (default=None) Number of jobs to run in parallel. None means 1 unless in a joblib.parallel_backend context. -1 means using all processors...

So, while this won't distribute across threads, it will distribute across processors; thereby achieving a degree of parallelization.

Comment: This uses cross validation.  I have a 3 datasets training/validation/testing.  My datasets are rather large so using standard 5 fold CV means I have to run 5 different possibilites versus just one using a dedicated validation set.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I found some code authored by @skylander86 on [GitHub](https://github.com/skylander86/ycml/blob/master/ycml/classifiers/gridsearch.py) in where the author uses:

```
param_scores = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(delayed(_fit_classifier)(klass, self.classifier_args, param, self.metric, X_train, Y_train, X_validation, Y_validation) for param in ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
```

I hope that helps.